# WiFi Speed Drops by 90% During and After Calls on Dell XPS Even After Replacing WiFi Card

Tags: wifi-configuration, dell-xps, wifi-driver

```
XPS 15 9550
i7-6700HQ @ 2.60GHz
Windows 10

New Wifi card: Intel Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz
```

200MB up on WiFi after restarting. 2-10MB up during and after calls. Read that it's an issue with the Killer card in the picture, replaced with Intel card. Obviously new drivers. Still getting the same issue. Should I assume hardware at this point (motherboard connection?) or is there something else I can do?

old card out, new speed:
[image]

Comment: What kind of "calls"? Skype or Teams on the laptop or calls on your mobile or cordless phones?

Comment: The issue occurred during any video call, and seemed especially adverse while screen sharing.

Answer (score 0):

After a month of messing with drivers, registry settings, WiFi sleep settings, replacing the network card, etc I got 2MB on a video call yesterday. As a last ditch effort, I turned off ALL energy saver settings. Somehow the video card settings were breaking this. I get 250 down now.

> Windows search --> Power Plan --> Change Advanced Power Settings --> Intel Graphics Setttings --> Graphics Power Plan --> set everything to "Maximum Performance"

This makes no sense, but it took me from 2MB to 250MB down. Dells are magical...

Hope this helps someone.

> [image: Annotated screenshot of all of the steps in this process.]